# Not able to #import Authorize.Net header file

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, authorize.net

I followed the instruction on this site http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/ and dragged and dropped the XCode project file of the SDK but still am not able to reference the Header files in the xcode project. I am trying to do a #import for AuthNet.h but not able to load it even though the project is in my Project. I also tried to put it in the workspace and still cannot import.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [this sample project](https://github.com/sibahota059/AuthorizeNetPaymentTest/tree/master) from below link : https://github.com/sibahota059/AuthorizeNetPaymentTest/tree/master